# Flutter : Control a tab bar action visible or hide

Tags: flutter, hide, tabbar, visible

my application give the user to control the tab bar to visible or hide according what they want. User can set which tab bar they want in the system. So is it possible to make it happen? Really appreciate for any help. Because I'm kinda newbie in this Flutter.

Attach here is the code example.

```
bottom: TabBar(
      controller: _controller,
      isScrollable: true,
      tabs: [
         Tab(
           text: 'Consignment',
         ),
         Tab(
           text: 'POD',
         ),
         Tab(
           text: 'Invoices',
         ),
       ],
     )),
 body: const TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
```

Comment: can you clarify what you wanna do exactly, is it that the user should navigate over screens using tabBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @Aqilah Mokhtarudin.
Welcome on StackOverflow.

It's totally possible, what you would have to do, is to make your list of `Tabs` a variable.
Then [add](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/List/add.html) or [remove](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/List/remove.html) items from the list, using the corresponding methods.

You will have to make the children of your `TabBarView` corresponding to the number of elements of your list.

Comment: Hi !! Thank you so much for your fast respond. Can you give me some example in code ?

Comment: It depends of the architecture of your file and code, without more code, I can't provide you with a great example, maybe try to make an example of your project on zapp.run & share me a link.

Comment: Here is the link example of the project. [ https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-z4806f54906?lazy=false&split=50&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/dashboard.dart ]

Comment: Here's your sample @AqilahMokhtarudin
https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-z2e06q43f06?lazy=false&split=50&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/dashboard.dart

Comment: Thank you so muchhh. Your sample really help me and give me idea on how to handle it.